# Indexing list count within last month

Tags: ravendb

I would like to be able to query the first 10 documents from a collection in RavenDB ordered by the count with a constraint in a sublist. This is my entity:

```
public class Post
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<Like> Likes { get; set; }
}

public class Like
{
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
}
```

I've tried with the following query:

```
var oneMonthAgo = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-1);
session
    .Query<Post>()
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Likes.Count(y => y.Created > oneMonthAgo))
    .Take(10);
```

Raven complaints that count should be done on index time rather than query time. I've tried moving the count to a index using the following code:

```
public class PostsIndex : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Post>
{
    public PostsIndex()
    {
        var month = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-1);
        Map = posts => from doc in posts
                       select
                           new
                               {
                                   doc.Title,
                                   LikeCount = doc.Likes.Count(x => x.Created > month),
                               };
    }
}
```

When adding this index, Raven throws a error 500.

What to do?

Comment: This actually a very hard thing to ask Raven to do.  It can be done, but it would require something like [this](https://github.com/mj1856/RavenDB-TemporalVersioning/blob/master/Raven.Bundles.Tests.TemporalVersioning/Indexes/Employees_TemporalCount.cs).  It may be possible to change your model to make this easier.  I will give it some thought and post an answer in a few days if nobody else comes up with something first.

Comment: Sounds great, Matt. I'm willing to change by model if you could give me directions to the right path?

Comment: There are a few techniques, none of them great.  The "now" can't exist in the index - it has to be either passed in at time of query, or updated via reference document.  Sometimes inverting the concept of "query events that happened x time ago" to "index from time of event x time forward" can work.  You might need to map/reduce the likes in order to count them - or you might do some of this work client-side.  There is also the [clock docs](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/ravendb/ZnvfKSsI_RM/hoi-ijHBjWYJ) concept, which can put stress on the server.  It's not an easy answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by creating a Map/Reduce index to flatten the Posts/Likes and then query over that.

The index:

```
public class PostLikesPerDay : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Post, PostLikesPerDay.Result>
{
    public PostLikesPerDay()
    {
        Map = posts => from post in posts
                        from like in post.Likes
                        select new Result
                        {
                            Title = post.Title,
                            Date = like.Created,
                            Likes = 1
                        };

        Reduce = results => from result in results
                            group result by new
                            {
                                result.Title, 
                                result.Date.Date
                            }
                            into grp
                            select new Result
                            {
                                Title = grp.Key.Title,
                                Date = grp.Key.Date,
                                Likes = grp.Sum(l => l.Likes)
                            };
    }

    public class Result
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public int Likes { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And the query:

```
using (var session = store.OpenSession())
{
    var oneMonthAgo = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-1);
    var query = session.Query<PostLikesPerDay.Result, PostLikesPerDay>()
                        .Where(y => y.Date > oneMonthAgo)
                        .OrderByDescending(p => p.Likes)
                        .Take(10);

    foreach (var post in query)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("'{0}' has {1} likes on  {2:d}", post.Title, post.Likes, post.Date);
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks very promising. The group uses the Created property from the Like object. The property is a DateTime containing both date and time. I guess the group doesn't group by the entire day but one group per ms, right? Isn't this a bug?

Comment: You are right it's a bug, in my test code I used only whole dates. I have updated the sample code.